# onChange antd Input component doesn't setState (hook) properly with list from axios get in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios, antd

I'm new to React, been working on it for the past week. I'm trying to make a simple app that has a 'product create' form and a list of products with a search bar (using Input component from antd); in the list I can click on any product to open the details page.

Right now I'm blocked by some not properly working logic or something I miss. When I tried the Input onChange with an Array I created in the code it worked fine, but now that I'm using a mock api (from fakestoreapi.com to be precise), I can't make it work.

**ProductsList.tsx**

```
function ProductsList() {
  const [list, setList] = useState<Array<Product>>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {   // I think something is wrong here
    ProductService.getAll()
      .then((res: any) => {
        setList(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => console.log(e));
  }, []);  // tried: 'query' const from state, 'filterList' from state 
  
  function onChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {   // Or here (or both here and in useEffect)
    console.log('in onChange');
    const filterList: Array<Product> = list.filter((item) =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    );
    setList(filterList);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Spin spinning={loading}>
        <List
          header={
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search product"
              allowClear
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          }
          split
          dataSource={list}
          renderItem={(item) => (
            <List.Item key={item.id}>
              <Link to={`/products/${item.id}`}>{item.title}</Link>
            </List.Item>
          )}
        ></List>
      </Spin>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductsList;
```

I tried adding some dependencies to the useEffect hook, but maybe they were the wrong ones. As I said, with a local array this worked, but now after loading the full list once, when I get to the Input and search something, the list is deleted. I think I spotted the problem in the fact that I don't reset the list to the full one, but I don't actually know how to do that (that's why I'm here). I tried to search something online but except for dependencies, I didn't find something specific to help me.

If needed, here is the `ProductService.getAll()` function:

```
function getAll() {   // http is axios
    return http.get<Array<Product>>(`/products`);
}
```

I'll be glad to add everything that could be helpful if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [list, setList] = useState<Array<Product>>([]); // The full list
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState<Array<Product>>([]); // the list you display

  function onChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {   // Or here (or both here and in useEffect)
    console.log('in onChange');
    const temp: Array<Product> = list.filter((item) => //keep the filter on the full list but only display the filtered list
      item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilteredList(temp);
  }
//the datasource: dataSource={filteredList}
```

Comment: This works, but I think misses a `setFilteredList(list)` in the useEffect hook, no? Because like this the initial filteredList is blank until I search something. Anyway, thank you! This was easy but I don't know why I couldn't think of it

Comment: fair enough, just add setFilteredList(res.data); below setList(res.data); in your useEffect.